# Not able to draw a proper Linear graph where X is date timestamp

Tags: java, android, mpandroidchart, android-graphview

Graph looks okay when I draw it with graphView http://prntscr.com/hjg501 (tested with plot.ly: http://prntscr.com/hjgiim)

And then graph looks bad when using hellochart/mpchart:

Hellochart: http://prntscr.com/hjg8fa

MPChart: http://prntscr.com/hjghbb

My dataset on both graphs is this (X, Y):

`1512488280000   1.200000048
1512488310000   1.200000048
1512488346000   1.200000048
1512488370000   3.599999905
1512488400000   1.200000048
1512488430000   1.200000048
1512488460000   1.200000048
1512488490000   1.200000048
1512488524000   1.200000048
1512488550000   6
1512488580000   1.200000048
1512488612000   1.200000048
1512488646000   1.200000048
1512488674000   3.599999905
1512488702000   1.200000048
1512488730000   1.200000048
1512488760000   6
1512488790000   1.200000048
1512488820000   1.200000048
1512488850000   1.200000048
1512488880000   2.400000095
1512488910000   1.200000048
1512488940000   1.200000048
1512488970000   1.200000048
1512489000000   1.200000048
1512489030000   1.200000048
1512489060000   12
1512489090000   1.200000048
1512489126000   13.19999981
1512489150000   7.199999809`

I see that in hellochart and mpchart graphs look the same, while in graphview it shows properly, so I must be doing something wrong then...

Is there a way to make it work?

Comment: can you please share your code for mpcharts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved. Turns out that most of libraries don't normalize values and rely on doubles/floats. Only library which currently accepts long ints is GraphView, but it's very limited and basically deprecated. So it's up to us to normalize values before populating the dataSet.

All I needed to do is normalize X values before adding to the plot dataset. I decided to rely on differences rather then on some common divisor.

So for example you have these points:

```
x1 1512488280000   y1 1.200000048

x2 1512488310000   y2 1.200000048

x3 1512488346000   y3 1.200000048

x4 1512488370000   y4 3.599999905
```

Normalized dataset calculation:

If you calculate x1x2Diff (difference between x1 and x2) you will get 30000 for x2Point in our new dataset, and x1Point set it as 0 (because what we are interested is keeping same differences between points).

x2x3Diff is 36000 (and you will need to keep track of previous x value or just simply add up previous point, so x3Point= x2x3Diff+x2Point=66000  (in our new dataset).

Finally x3x4Diff is 24000 so x4Point=x3x4Diff+x3Point=90000.

Finally, this is our new normalized dataset(which will draw proper graphs in such libraries as hellocharts and mpcharts):

```
 0     1.200000048

30000 1.200000048

66000 1.200000048

90000 3.599999905
```

Now you can also check if you did it correctly by calculating x1x4Diff in the original dataset, and the gap is 90000.

Also note, that you can make a variable which will keep track of latest value, because this example is to show how it works (that's why I broke it down step by step).